# Can method used in the .append() in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to JQuery. I want to use JQuery to realize a function that can take the content of the input and put the content into a list. Now I got a problem:
this is part of the HTML code.

```
    <body>
        <form name="checkListForm">
            <input type="text" name="checkListItem"/>
        </form>
        <div id="button">Add!</div>
        <br/>
        <div class="list"></div>
    </body>
```

This is the JQuery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#button').click(function(){
        var toAdd = $('input[name=checkListItem]').val();
        $('.list').append('.div'.addClass('item').html(toAdd));
    });  
});
```

I am trying to realize this: When I input something and click the button, the content will be stored in the `toAdd`, and a new div with `class="item"` and `toAdd` content will be appended in the list. I know there is another correct method to realize this:

```
 $('.list').append('<div class="item">' + toAdd + '</div>');
```

So I just wonder why my code does not work here?

Comment: It's `.val()` not `.val`. You're also missing a `)` in your append, although even `.append('.div')` doesn't make a whole lotta sense.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that, I edited it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Correct the typo at `.val`, it is method not property  hence add `()(parenthesis)`
- `$('<div>')` will create `jQuery` object of empty `div` element

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#button').click(function() {
    var toAdd = $('input[name=checkListItem]').val();
    $('.list').append($('<div>', {
      class: 'item',
      html: toAdd
    }));
  });
});
```

```css
.item {
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="checkListForm">
  <input type="text" name="checkListItem" />
</form>
<div id="button">Add!</div>
<br/>
<div class="list"></div>
```

Comment: `$('<div />')` is ok to create new div.

Comment: Your code is right! This is my understanding, I do not know if it is right.So, at first, if any element wants to use a jquery method , it must become a jquery element , using $(' ').  Second, I can not use $('.list').append($('.div').addClass('item').html(toAdd)); . Is it because that .div is focusing on the div that already exist in the html?

Comment: @Doris, `$('.div')` will select the element having class as `div` from DOM

Comment: @Rayon, you are right. I really do not know what I am thinking when I am coding....